# Azure App Service authentication behind a reverse-proxy

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I'm working with Authentication in Azure App Service, AKA "Easy Authentication"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview

It works fine if I browse my azure web-site using it's Azure name: [myid].azurewebsites.net
But if place my web-site behind a reverse proxy, after authentication, I'm always redirected to [myid].azurewebsites.net instead of www.[mydomain].com. The reverse proxy is correctly configured to serve my pages and all work fine without authentication.

I think that the root cause is how the redirect_uri parameter is built by "Easy Authentication". Using Chrome F12 I noticed that during the initial redirect to authentication service, the browser url is built using [myid].azurewebsites.net instead of www.[mydomain].com.

https://login.windows.net/034...51/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyid.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&......

I can't find a way to instruct/force "Easy Authentication" to use www.[mydomain].com

Any suggestions or idea?

--- update ---
I use Nginx as reverse-proxy. The relevant fragment of the configuration file (redacted):

```
server {
        server_name www.mydomain.com;
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ...
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Host $host;
                proxy_pass https://myid.azurewebsites.net/;
        }
}
```

Comment: How did you implement the reverse proxy, URL Rewrite? Please update your question and provide more details.

Comment: @BruceChen question updated. The reverse-proxy itself works fine. Perhaps any additional header could help "Easy Auth" to understand that there is reverse-proxy behind, but I haven't found any documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

We need to include an extra parameter to instruct where the process should redirect to after successful authentication. We can do this with the 'post_login_redirect_uri' parameter. Without this, the process will redirect to a default 'Authentication Successful' page with a link to go back to the site.

For more details, refer to this document: https://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/easy-auth-app-service-authentication-using-multiple-providers.

Comment: post_login_redirect_uri does not solve my problem. It is used after successfully authentication to redirect user to a target page. What I need is way to "inject" www.mydomain.com in the first authentication URL (login.windows.net/.....) instead of myid.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I used [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [Azure Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) as my reverse-proxy to test this issue, I found that I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned. I also tried to compare `Headers`、`ServerVariables` between accessing via reverse-proxy and directly accessing, and tried to override the related headers to narrow this issue, but failed in the end. I assumed that since we are using the build-in App Service Authentication / Authorization, we could not override the generating for the `redirect_uri` parameter.

Per my understanding, you could set the additional header(s) under your reverse-proxy, then build the authentication / Authorization in your application to pick up the additional header for generating the `redirect_uri` and redirect user to the related authorize endpoint. Or you could use [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) for Load Balancer, and you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718763/using-azure-traffic-manager-with-mobile-app/46726393#46726393). Additionally, if you just want to customize your azure web app domain, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: You're right. Currently "EasyAuth" does not allow to inject custom redirect_uri.  https://twitter.com/fhtino/status/943143332418596864    :(

Comment: I would recommend you leverage [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) and it is not expensive. Details you could follow [Traffic Manager pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/traffic-manager/). Moreover, you could also follow [Map domains with Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name).