# Must a Custom Azure App Service Authentication provider reside on the same app service as the client?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

We're building a new web system which has a React front end (App service 1). We are looking to enable social login to the app but also want to provide a standard username/password sign in. To do this we're looking at developing a custom provider.

I've got a custom provider created and deployed to a new app service (App Service 2).

I'm picturing the flow of authentication as:
User Accesses Front end client (unauthenticated) >> Redirect to Login page on Custom provider >> Generate token and redirect back to the front end app.

Is this the correct flow or am I going about it completely wrong? I'm curious as to whether accessing /.auth/me will work once I redirect back to the client app (I think it would more so work on App Service 2?).

So the question is, must custom authentication and the generation of a token occur on the same App Service as the front end client?

Cheers
Dave

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is, must custom authentication and the generation of a token occur on the same App Service as the front end client?

According to your description, you are using [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). If you create another web app for custom logging, you need to make sure the `signKey` is the same as your App service 1 and `audience`,`issuer` equals `https://{your-app-service-1}.azurewebsites.net/` when you generating the JWT token within your App service 2. For configuring the signkey in your App service 2, you could add a `WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY` app setting with the value from your App service 1. You could find the `WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY` key via [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and access `https://{your-app-service-1}.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml`.

For accessing your app service, you could send the request as follows:

```
GET https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/xxxxx
Header x-zumo-auth:{authenticationToken}
```

Moreover, here is a similar issue, you could follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718763/using-azure-traffic-manager-with-mobile-app/).